# My keyboard only works in the last-opened window

Tags: keyboard, 15.04, ubuntu-gnome

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04. When I try to switch windows, my keyboard only works in the previous window unless I minimize it.

For example, I open Chrome and the Terminal. I open the Terminal first. When I switch to Chrome and attempt to type in the address bar, I'm apparently still typing in the Terminal window, even though my Chrome window is active. This doesn't fix itself until I minimize the offending window--in this case, the Terminal.

It happens with any applications that accept keyboard input: web browsers, text editors, etc.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it a standard Ubuntu 15.04 or some fork?

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm using Ubuntu GNOME.

Comment: Have you tried a left mouse click in the destination window? How do you "switch windows"?

Comment: @waltinator Yes, I've left-clicked, right-clicked, middle-clicked, everything. I have two monitors, so I switch windows just by clicking on the window I want to use. Copy and paste doesn't work in the new window, either. No keyboard shortcuts or anything.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was wrong. I needed to change this setting: Tweak Tools > Windows > Window Action Key to `Alt`. For some reason, this setting was blank and it was causing all my problems.